# \maketitle to use several times with combine in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am trying to make a .tex template for a book of abstracts for the conference. I want the template to be compilable, so the participants are able to see their abstracts separately before submitting. Moreover I want to use the files to compile the book of abstracts with table of contents and titles.

So, I have master file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{combine}
\usepackage{authblk}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \begin{papers}

        \coltocauthor{Crist\'{o}bal Josevich Junta, Fyodor Simeonovich Kivrin}
        \coltoctitle{Title of the first abstract}
        \import{first}

        \coltocauthor{Roman Oyra-Oyra}
        \coltoctitle{Title of the second abstract}
        \import{second}

    \end{papers} 
    
\end{document}
```

And two imported files are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{Title of the first abstract}

\author[1]{Crist\'{o}bal Josevich Junta}
\author[2]{Fyodor Simeonovich Kivrin}

\affil[1]{Department of the Meaning of Life}
\affil[2]{Department of Linear Happiness}


\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    
    Text of the first abstract. 

\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Title of the second abstract}
\author[1]{Roman Oyra-Oyra}
\affil[1]{Laboratory of the most unexpected sciences}


\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle

    Text of the second abstract. 

\end{document}
```

The problem is the second `\maketitle` does not print authors names and their affiliation.

I have tried using redefined `\settitle` instead of `\maketitle`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\settitle}{\@maketitle}
\makeatother
```

it did not help.

Also, I tried `titling` package, which led to no change.

I want `\maketitle` to print the names and affiliations or to find out the better way to automatically make titles for each abstract.